# OpenESB - different environments

Tags: wsdl, soa, esb, bpel, open-esb

I am developing a service layer app which provides a catalog of webservices, then I am orchestrating them using OpenESB.

I create my BPELs importing external WSDL definitions using `http://localhost:8080/services/myService?wsdl`.

The problem is -- these BPELs strongly depend on this specific URL, and when I deploy on production server, my ESB layer stops working.

How can I make my BPELs independent of the specific endpoint? Can I refer the URIs to an external config file?

Answer (score 0):

To do it you must create application configuration and application variable and add them on your http address. Example: "http://${MyHtttpAddress}:${MyHttpPort}/service1/myService?wsdl"/>.
Applications and variable are set up in the administrative console and can be changed for each environment.

Regards

Paul

Comment: That sounds perfect but how exactly do you "create application configuration"?